# Multiple Bluetooth Connections on Android 2 devices

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am trying to allow two devices to have 4 connections in parallel. I have tried different UUIDs with no success (socket is closed error messages after connect). I have tried the same UUID, same errors; except, I think I have had 2 connections, though I need 4 to properly test the app.

Is there a way to connect it? Will these multiple connections be faster than one connection that I sort data through into 4 sudo connections?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13381575/318938 Here the commenter mentions unregistering an sdp, as the mac address was stopping multiple connections. Any ideas of where to find some example code to try unregistering SDP?

Comment: Not sure if the API will let you do that but i will really doubt it will be faster, bluetooth bandwidth will be splitted

Comment: I was hoping for some reason the hardware was more capable of handling multiple signals better than software; perhaps better streamlined, but yes I am worried this is all futile. I wonder what the consensus will be.