# How to create multiple bluetooth socket connection between Android device and PC?

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth

```
UUID u = UUID.fromString(MY_UUID);
BluetoothSocket btsoc = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(u);
btsoc.connect();
```

This will create the bluetooth connection with PC. Can I create another socket connection with different UUID?
In normal socket, we could distinguish it with port number on one IP address.

Comment: Is it possible to open multiple sockets between two devices with same uuid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create many connections using different UUIDs.
You can check this question ([Multiple bluetooth connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943182/multiple-bluetooth-connection)) for further details.

;)