# Android - connecting to multiple bluetooth devices without pairing

Tags: android, bluetooth, rfcomm, insecure-connection

I have a bunch of devices that are non-discoverable but I know the MAC addresses for them. At present I can connect to multiple devices using this in my ConnectThread:

```
Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket",new Class[] { int.class });

tmp = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, 1);
```

Problem being that I want to support insecure RFCOMM for devices previous to 2.3. I then [found this](http://mobisocial.stanford.edu/news/2011/03/bluetooth-reflection-and-legacy-nfc/) on another answer which lets me do this instead:

```
tmp = InsecureBluetooth.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(device,MY_UUID, true);
```

Which works perfectly in connecting to a single device without the need for pairing.

My question is how can I get the best of both worlds and use reflection on the InsecureBluetooth class as well? Or does it need to be done within the InsecureBluetooth class and if so how? Here is the relevant part of the InsecureBluetooth class:

```
private static BluetoothSocket createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(
        BluetoothDevice device, int port, UUID uuid, boolean encrypt)
        throws IOException {
    try {
        BluetoothSocket socket = null;
        Constructor<BluetoothSocket> constructor = BluetoothSocket.class
                .getDeclaredConstructor(int.class, int.class, boolean.class,
                        boolean.class, BluetoothDevice.class, int.class, ParcelUuid.class);
        if (constructor == null)
            throw new RuntimeException("can't find the constructor for socket");

        constructor.setAccessible(true);
        Field f_rfcomm_type = BluetoothSocket.class
                .getDeclaredField("TYPE_RFCOMM");
        f_rfcomm_type.setAccessible(true);
        int rfcomm_type = (Integer) f_rfcomm_type.get(null);
        socket = constructor.newInstance(new Object[] { rfcomm_type, -1, false,
                true, device, port, uuid != null ? new ParcelUuid(uuid) : null });
        return socket;
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        if (e.getCause() instanceof IOException) {
            throw (IOException) e.getCause();
        }
        throw new RuntimeException(e.getCause());
    }
}

public static BluetoothSocket createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(
        BluetoothDevice device, UUID uuid, boolean encrypt) throws IOException {
    return createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(device, -1, uuid, encrypt);
}

public static BluetoothSocket createRfcommSocket(BluetoothDevice device,
        int port, boolean encrypt) throws IOException {
    return createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(device, port, null, encrypt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following class to create unsecure bluetooth socket connection. It automatically handles reflections to offer this feature for SDK below 2.3.3

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.UUID;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.ParcelUuid;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Class to offer unsecure bluetooth socket connection.<br />
 * It was intended to be used when building the app with API version below 10 (API < Android2.3.3)
 * @author waa
 *
 */
@SuppressWarnings("all")
public class UnpairedBluetooth {
    static private class InUse extends RuntimeException {
    }

    public static BluetoothServerSocket listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(BluetoothAdapter adapter, String name, UUID uuid, boolean encrypt) throws IOException {
        try {
            Class c_rfcomm_channel_picker = null;
            Class[] children = BluetoothAdapter.class.getDeclaredClasses();
            for(Class c : children) {
                Log.e("TO", "class " + c.getCanonicalName());
                if(c.getCanonicalName().equals(BluetoothAdapter.class.getName() + ".RfcommChannelPicker")) {
                    c_rfcomm_channel_picker = c;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(c_rfcomm_channel_picker == null)
                throw new RuntimeException("can't find the rfcomm channel picker class");

            Constructor constructor = c_rfcomm_channel_picker.getDeclaredConstructor(UUID.class);
            if(constructor == null)
                throw new RuntimeException("can't find the constructor for rfcomm channel picker");
            Object rfcomm_channel_picker = constructor.newInstance(new Object[] {uuid});
            Method m_next_channel = c_rfcomm_channel_picker.getDeclaredMethod("nextChannel", new Class[] {});
            m_next_channel.setAccessible(true);

            BluetoothServerSocket socket = null;

            int channel;
            int errno;
            while (true) {
                channel = (Integer)m_next_channel.invoke(rfcomm_channel_picker, new Object[] {});

                if (channel == -1) {
                    throw new IOException("No available channels");
                }

                try {
                    socket = listenUsingRfcomm(channel, encrypt);
                    break;
                } catch(InUse e) {
                    continue;
                }
            }

            Field f_internal_service = adapter.getClass().getDeclaredField("mService");
            f_internal_service.setAccessible(true);
            Object internal_service = f_internal_service.get(adapter);

            Method m_add_rfcomm_service_record = internal_service.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("addRfcommServiceRecord", new Class[] {String.class, ParcelUuid.class, int.class, IBinder.class});
            m_add_rfcomm_service_record.setAccessible(true);

            int handle = (Integer)m_add_rfcomm_service_record.invoke(internal_service, new Object[] { name, new ParcelUuid(uuid), channel, new Binder() } );

            if (handle == -1) {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {}
                throw new IOException("Not able to register SDP record for " + name);
            }
            Field f_internal_handler = adapter.getClass().getDeclaredField("mHandler");
            f_internal_handler.setAccessible(true);
            Object internal_handler = f_internal_handler.get(adapter);

            Method m_set_close_handler = socket.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setCloseHandler", new Class[] {Handler.class, int.class});
            m_set_close_handler.setAccessible(true);

            m_set_close_handler.invoke(socket, new Object[] { internal_handler, handle});
            return socket;
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch(IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch(InstantiationException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch(InvocationTargetException e) {
            if(e.getCause() instanceof IOException) {
                throw (IOException)e.getCause();
            }
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getCause());
        }   
    }
    private static BluetoothServerSocket listenUsingRfcomm(/*BluetoothAdapter adapter, */ int port, boolean encrypt, boolean reuse) throws IOException, InUse {
        BluetoothServerSocket socket = null;
        try {
            Constructor<BluetoothServerSocket> constructor = BluetoothServerSocket.class.getDeclaredConstructor(int.class, boolean.class, boolean.class, int.class);
            if(constructor == null)
                throw new RuntimeException("can't find the constructor");
            constructor.setAccessible(true);
            Field f_rfcomm_type = BluetoothSocket.class.getDeclaredField("TYPE_RFCOMM");
            f_rfcomm_type.setAccessible(true);
            int rfcomm_type = (Integer)f_rfcomm_type.get(null);

            Field f_e_addr_in_use = BluetoothSocket.class.getDeclaredField("EADDRINUSE");
            f_e_addr_in_use.setAccessible(true);
            int e_addr_in_use = (Integer)f_e_addr_in_use.get(null);

            socket = constructor.newInstance(new Object[] { rfcomm_type, false, encrypt, port } );

            Field f_internal_socket = socket.getClass().getDeclaredField("mSocket");
            f_internal_socket.setAccessible(true);
            Object internal_socket = f_internal_socket.get(socket);
            Method m_bind_listen = internal_socket.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("bindListen", new Class[] {});
            m_bind_listen.setAccessible(true);
            Object result = m_bind_listen.invoke(internal_socket, new Object[] {});

            int errno = (Integer)result;
            if(reuse && errno == e_addr_in_use) {
                throw new InUse();
            } else if (errno != 0) {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {}
                internal_socket.getClass().getMethod("throwErrnoNative", new Class[] {int.class}).invoke(internal_socket, new Object[] { errno });
            }
            return socket;
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch(IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch(InstantiationException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch(InvocationTargetException e) {
            if(e.getCause() instanceof IOException) {
                throw (IOException)e.getCause();
            }
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getCause());
        }
    }
    public static BluetoothServerSocket listenUsingRfcomm(int port, boolean encrypt) throws IOException {
        return listenUsingRfcomm(port, encrypt, false);
    }
    private static BluetoothSocket createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(BluetoothDevice device, int port, UUID uuid, boolean encrypt) throws IOException {
        try {
            BluetoothSocket socket = null;
            Constructor<BluetoothSocket> constructor = BluetoothSocket.class.getDeclaredConstructor(
                    int.class, int.class, boolean.class, boolean.class, BluetoothDevice.class, int.class, ParcelUuid.class);
            if(constructor == null)
                throw new RuntimeException("can't find the constructor for socket");

            constructor.setAccessible(true);
            Field f_rfcomm_type = BluetoothSocket.class.getDeclaredField("TYPE_RFCOMM");
            f_rfcomm_type.setAccessible(true);
            int rfcomm_type = (Integer)f_rfcomm_type.get(null);
//          socket = constructor.newInstance(new Object[] { rfcomm_type, -1, false, true, device, port, uuid != null ? new ParcelUuid(uuid) : null} );
            socket = constructor.newInstance(new Object[] { rfcomm_type, -1, false, encrypt, device, port, uuid != null ? new ParcelUuid(uuid) : null} );
            return socket;
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch(IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch(InstantiationException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch(InvocationTargetException e) {
            if(e.getCause() instanceof IOException) {
                throw (IOException)e.getCause();
            }
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getCause());
        }
    }
    public static BluetoothSocket createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(BluetoothDevice device, UUID uuid, boolean encrypt) throws IOException{
        return createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(device, -1, uuid, encrypt);
    }
    public static BluetoothSocket createRfcommSocket(BluetoothDevice device, int port, boolean encrypt) throws IOException {
        return createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(device, port, null, encrypt);
    }
}
```

For more info, refer to [this](http://mobisocial.stanford.edu/news/2011/03/bluetooth-reflection-and-legacy-nfc/) link.

Comment: Yes, that is the same class and link as the one I included in my question. The problem is that when I do a while loop on each device it overrides the device I am already connecting to when using this method. I will update my question to explain more what I mean.

Comment: i think you can connect to one device at a time for the same bluetooth profile. isn't it?

Comment: yes, but I want to connect to multiple devices at the same time and perform data retrieval on each one in the background.

Comment: perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943182/multiple-bluetooth-connection) may help you