# How to listen from two Bluetooth devices simultaneously into an android mobile application?

Tags: android

I am working on an android app which needs to communicate with two external Bluetooth devices simultaneously and read the data from those ,process the data and show on the screen.

Will it be possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple bluetooth connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943182/multiple-bluetooth-connection)

Answer (score 1):

your question is similar to another post
[Multiple bluetooth connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943182/multiple-bluetooth-connection)
There you can find your answer.
Regards

Comment: Additionally a better post personally : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21237093/android-4-3-how-to-connect-to-multiple-bluetooth-low-energy-devices