# Is it possible to connect and communicate with two different Bluetooth devices simultaneously?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I was wondering, I want to develop an app that communicates with two different Bluetooth devices serving different functions, and I would like to use them at the same time to display data from both devices simultaneously.

I was wondering, is this possible?  If so, does anyone have any examples of such a use case?  I couldn't find any such examples anywhere.

Comment: It may help to explain how the existing Bluetooth Chat sample wouldn't be a good starting point for your problem: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothChat

Comment: I tried that example and when I try to connect to two devices it disconnects from the other device.

Comment: You'll need to change it work with multiple clients. Here is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943182/multiple-bluetooth-connection