# Is it possible to get 3 or more android devices to triangulate with each other via bluetooth?

Tags: android, networking, bluetooth, gps, location

I am looking for a solution to pair 3 or more bluetooth devices to be able to draw distance and direction in reference to each other.

Allowing each device to see the other devices positioning, placing each device in center view of its own display.

Considering developing an app if possible...

Can use phones as the beacons or arduino/raspberry devices that can feed the APP (android).

[Display sample.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2r5AE.jpg)

On another note: WiFi is on the table....

Answer (score 0):

Nice idea! There isn't a method that reurtn the distance between two smatphone with bluetooth, but maybe you can calculate it with bluetooth's signal strength. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15312858/get-bluetooth-signal-strength) a question that deals with it but i fear that it depends on bluetooth module of each smartphone...

Comment: It really is, imagine Aliens (the movie) the motion sensor that the marines had... Now imagine using this between your team mates in a game of woodsball (paintball)..;O)

Comment: I think the way to go is with the signal strength (Bluetooth or WiFi) and calibrate each device. Example: freind stand here with your device (predetermined 10 feet) read signal strength, now stand here (20 feet) and POW signal strength = aprox. distance. Now to tackle the triangulatión:

Comment: Have the device do the same with a second (or more beacons) and read the data from those beacons (including compass info), POW, triangulation. Directión + Distance.

Answer (score 0):

-

1. Connecting more than 2 devices?

Checkout `BluetoothAdapter` class using which you can connect two devices (one as a server and another client), So if u could with connect 3 phones (1 Server and 2 client). Both client devices will have to communicate through server device refer to [this Bluetooth doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#ConnectingAsAServer) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943182/multiple-bluetooth-connection)

1. About calculating distance?

There is no way you can calculate distance between bluetooth connected devices, and calculating it from signal strength would be fuzzy (eg. any other object between devices can lead to signal distortion and lead to miscalculation). Good luck

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. I edited my post to include that WiFi is a viable option.