# Connect multiple devices via Bluetooth on Android (Multiple BLE connections)

Tags: android, github, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to create Client-Server connection network over android devices via blue-tooth(as the connection platform).One device acting as Server and other 4 or five devices as Clients.I have tried many examples from git-hub repository but there is no multi-connectivity implementation.Here is the link I tried for multi connection via blue-tooth
https://github.com/arissa34/Android-Multi-Bluetooth-Library

Comment: will u share some more outputs about the tries ? what actually fails in the corresponding codes

Comment: @SamirBhatt Thankyou for your response but I have tried that link earlier I am unable to scan the near by BLE device,are there any alternatives for multi-connections please let me know

Comment: I successfully build the code and run the application but I am facing issue while the server has to perform scanning operation to near by devices it is not scanning the devices it is displaying me the white screen with the title  "Scanning Bluetooth devices".I am unable to see the near by devices so I can't move to next step "CONNECT" ??? Are there any alternative solutions  for this multiple connectivity using blue-tooth .Actually I have a few screenshots with me but I am unable to attach here.--@KingofMasses

Comment: I am unable to share screen shots as I have not reached the minimum reputations(10) for image attachments--@KingofMasses

Comment: This library code which your using is developed by @Rami https://stackoverflow.com/users/3411483/rami. Try to get his help

Comment: I hope now you can edit your question with screen shots and some more observations since u have enough reps

Comment: will you update the question with all the observations , i.e posted in comments and screenshots etc

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you have to notice this library is for socket communication using **RFCOMM protocol** which is not Low Bluetooth 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_protocols

If you want help, I need more informations, as your android version, a piece of your code and your logs as well.

Moreover, you can see this library in work on this game https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.drgames.domino Using one server and 3 clients in bluetooth.

Comment: Thanks for pointing us @Rami. Well we will update our question with all the details what u asked. mean time we just tried to run the sample code which is there in git hub, while the scanning operation is perform to near by devices it is not scanning the devices it is displaying me the white screen with the title "Scanning Bluetooth devices".

Comment: Thank you for your response @Rami. My intension is to connect the two or more ble's to a single ble android device.As I am beginner to ble technology I tried this connection using your library Rami but I couln't make it,now I am searching for the alternative solutions.Could you share me the library code file  for the game link you mentioned above