# Can a single Android phone connect to multiple bluetooth devices?

Tags: android, bluetooth, multiprocessing, device

I am about to create an "Intelligent" motorcycle helmet which will be able to play music, discuss with the passenger, send GPS information, notify of police, speech recognition etc... I have a few options to make this helmet like including an individual microprocessor for each helmet or connecting both passenger and driver helmet's microphone and speaker to a single Android phone, my question is; is it possible, to connect to 2 speaker and 2 microphones with Bluetooth and retrieve their informations individually (Like one thread per microphone and being able to send audio to a specific speaker). This could be the best solution for my problem so I don't need to worry about microprocessors and batteries inside the helmet, everything could be processed remotely by the driver's phone which would receive and send data to the individual speakers and microphones.
Thank you very much for your answers!
Best regards, Julien

Comment: [Multiple bluetooth connections](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3943182/8954451)

Answer (score 0):

You can only have a single Bluetooth connection. So you cannot connect two Bluetooth speakers at the same time. instead, you can use RF like the walkie-talkie in a half-duplex( only driver can send messages) or full-duplex(both can communicate with each other) transceiver.

Comment: Ok thank you very much, I will dig more into it in the next days !

Answer (score 0):

Android P allows up to five bluetooth connections at the same time. Regularly two connections are allowed, 5 can be activated as developer option.

https://www.androidauthority.com/android-p-bluetooth-audio-developer-options-844298/